# Makefile: how to delete file that contains $

Tags: makefile

I have the following remove command in my Makefile:

```
clean:
      rm -f ch2$Node.class
```

When I run the "make clean" command, it only executed "rm -f ch2Node.class". I used backslash but did not work. How do I delete the actual file with the name "ch2$Node.class"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent Make from interpreting it as variable access, you need to duplicate the dollar: `$$`.

You also need to stop the shell from thinking it's a variable access, either by adding `\` before `$$`, **or** by wrapping the filename in single quotes.

So, `rm -f ch2\$$Node.class` or `rm -f 'ch2$$Node.class'`.